# VSCode debug console keeps skipping to the top

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode debug console started recently to skip to the top instead of showing the results for the most recent command that was typed in the console. How to make it "pin down" to the bottom of the console to show the most recent output?

Answer (score 1):

When you type the name of the variable alone, the effect will be as described above, however, if you type `print(name_of_variable)`, the output will be shown at the bottom for that command and the subsequent commands.

Comment: This is not true for me, and I'm experiencing the same behavior.  I.e., when I type something like print(name_of_variable), the debug console still reverts to the top, instead of showing me what I just typed.  So, if I've typed a bunch of print(...) things, it's really annoying to then have to scroll to the bottom of the debug console.